# Not able to see the Service Provider listed under Identity Provider for Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, federated-authentication, delegated-authentication

Hi All I am facing an Issue while configuring SSO.  I have set identity provider and in one org and created Service provider in aother org.  However after creating the  service provider configuration  under  "Setup" > "Security Controls" > "Identity Provider"  done the settings.

When complete, I should end up with a new Service Provider listed under Identity Provider. However this is not happening for me what could be the possible reason? Am I missing any othere step below is the link I am following

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Implementing_Single_Sign-On_Across_Multiple_Organizations

Comment: Shebin, most questions are related to salesforce. There rarely a need to tag a question with "salesforce-crm". I've already removed it for you this time.